# "let" command is not found in my bash script

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script,

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $SHELL

i=1
for img in ../img/*.png; do
  echo $img
  new=$(printf "../img/tmp/pyr%d.png" "$i")
  echo $new
  # cp "$img" "$new"
  let i=i+1
done
# avconv -r 2  -i ../img/tmp/pyr%d.png -b:v 1000k ../pop_pyr.mp4
```

In the `../img` folder, there are files `pyr1920.png`, `pyr1925.png`, ...

When I run this script, I get this error

```
../img/pyr1920.png
../img/tmp/pyr1.png
make_video.sh: 10: make_video.sh: let: not found
../img/pyr1925.png
../img/tmp/pyr1.png
```

But I pasted the script in a terminal, it works perfectly fine.

```
../img/pyr1920.png
../img/tmp/pyr1.png
../img/pyr1925.png
../img/tmp/pyr2.png
```

My environment it ubuntu 14.04. I understand that default /bin/sh is dash. I make sure to use bash and check by `echo $SHELL`.

Why it doesn't work as a script but works fine from a terminal? I tried to find a solution but all I can find is about "dash" and "bash" setting.

Comment: That's not a `bash` error message; you aren't running your script with `bash`.

Comment: Thank you for the info, I will check and try them out.

Comment: @chepner, Yes, now I realized it works with "bash myscript.sh". Doesn't it run bash if I write "#!/bin/bash" on the top of the script?

Comment: It should; how are you running it? Incidentally, `$SHELL` does not contain the name of the current shell; it's the name of your default shell.

Comment: Even my default shell is /bin/bash, I checked just open a terminal and type $SHELL. I am confused.

Comment: `$SHELL` gives the name of the login shell.  If you want to know which shell you are using then type `ps|grep $$`.  How are you running the script?  By the way, you don't need `let`, just `(( i++ ))`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

do in this way:

```
i=$((i+1))
```

or

```
i=$(expr $i + 1)
```

Comment: If `$((...))` doesn't work, there's no reason to believe `expr` is available either.

Answer (score 7):

I am sorry for answering my question.
I was running my script with `sh script.sh` not `bash script.sh`. `bash script.sh` worked fine.

But isn't that I can specify it by `#!/bin/bash` on the top of a script?

Comment: If you run the script by passing its name as an argument to a specific interpreter (like `sh`), the shebang is ignored. It is only used when you make the script executable and run it directly (`chmod +x script.sh; ./script.sh`)

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment! It explained clearly and saved me a lot of time. I was stucked in this for long time.

Comment: @user26767: please accept an answer to prevent others spending time on this.

Comment: BTW, adding (and accepting if you like) your own answer is NOT a bad thing. We're working to accumulate knowledge, and that's part of the process.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same error, checking I found that with this code you get what you need

```
i=`expr $i + 1`
```